# How to use event touchstart on phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-maps, cordova-plugins

Now I have a problem using the click event.

I want Event touchstart.

Features of the app when the open app the camera is moving along my location.
My app used cordova angularjs and plugin phonegap-googlemaps-plugin.
If event touchstart the camera isn't moving along my location.

I did not used touchend.

If I have to set `map.setClickable(false)`.

I can not move on the map by touch but I can use  Event touchstart.
There are other ways I can touch keep moving along map and use touchstart.
I want to move on the map by touch and I want to use Event touchstart.

Answer (score 0):

Now I will solve the problem using. getMyLocation call () method and listening events. CAMERA_CHANGE
If the location of the camera exceeds certain limits. To follow the conditions set and the camera does not move to my place.

---

```
function onMapCameraChanged(position)
{
  lat = position.target.lat;
  lng = position.target.lng;
  map.getMyLocation(oncheckmylocation);
}
function oncheckmylocation (location)
{
  mylocation_lat = location.latLng.lat;
  mylocation_lng = location.latLng.lng;
  if((lat>=mylocation_lat+0.001||lat<=mylocation_lat-0.001||lng>=mylocation_lng+0.001||lng<=mylocation_lng-0.001)&auto_move_camera==true)
  {
    auto_move_camera = false;
  }
}
```